# Freemarker loop doesn't seems to print sequentially

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I am trying to make model code with getter and setter from a comma-separated string. But somewhere I am making a mistake or so, I am not getting it right.

```
package ${packageName};


    public class modelName{

    <#assign x = ''>
    <#list parameters?split(',') as x>
    private ${x};
    <#assign mappedArray = []>
    <#assign y = ''>
    <#list x?split(r'\s+', 'r') as y>
    <#assign mappedArray = mappedArray + [y]>
    </#list>

    public ${mappedArray[0]} get${mappedArray[1]}(){
    return ${mappedArray[1]};
    }

    public void set${mappedArray[1]}( ${mappedArray[0]} ${mappedArray[1]}){
    this.${mappedArray[1]} = ${mappedArray[1]};
    }

    </#list>
    }
```

I am giving `int id, String name` as parameters. I am expecting it to be split and we get x. From x I am trying to assign it to mappedAray and trying to print get and set function. But I am not getting the right output.

```
    package com.vindys.myapplication;


public class modelName {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public getString() {
        return String;
    }

    public int getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setid(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setString(String) {
        this.String = String;
    }

}
```

It writes for the first parameter, and later setter and getter is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are showing can't be the output of the template you are showing. So check if the template you are looking at is what's actually used. Because otherwise the template should work, though it's needlessly over-complicated. Like you split something to a sequence, and then build another totally identical sequence from it. Consider this, which does the same:

```
<#list parameters?split(',') as param>
<#assign paramWords = param?word_list>
<#assign type = paramWords[0]>
<#assign name = paramWords[1]>
private ${type} ${name};

public ${type} get${name?cap_first}(){
    return ${name};
}

public void set${name?cap_first}(${type} ${name}){
    this.${name} = ${name};
}
</#list>
```

Comment: I was trying input like

String name, int id, float amount

So first <#list is to split with comma and second loop with space.

But my code is working if its any other delimiter than space. I was trying in windows. 

Do you mean paramWords[0] would be String and paramWords[1] would be name if we use word_list? I am new to freemarker. So yet to explore word_list.

Comment: @VinodVarghese Yes, I meant that. But try this and see if there's any confusion left. Maybe fastest is to try on https://try.freemarker.apache.org.